# Not able to create Word documents using Open XML for SDK

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I have downloaded & installed Open XML for SDK 2.0 (It is technology preview version) still not able to add:

```
using Microsoft.Office.DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.
```

But able to add:

```
using Office = Microsoft.Office.DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using Microsoft.Office.DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
```

For this reason, or for some other I don't know, I'm not able to get my code work. Here is the code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WordprocessingDocument mydoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(TextBox1.Text, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = mydoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainPart.Document = new Document();
    Body body = new Body();
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    Run run_paragraph = new Run();
    Text text_paragraph = new Text("Hello World!");
    run_paragraph.Append(text_paragraph);
    paragraph.Append(run_paragraph);
    body.Append(paragraph);
    mainPart.Document.Append(body);
    mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

I'm getting errors on almost all lines like `mainPart.Document`, `body`, `paragraph` etc.. Where is the mistake?

Comment: I used to get the errors like Body is not referenced. Are u missing some assembly reference? Then i downloaded other version of open xml for sdk. Then I can add using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging; Then I'm able to create the document but not able to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a `using` statement and change your code to something like this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument mydoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(TextBox1.Text, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = mydoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainPart.Document = new Document();
    Body body = new Body();
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    Run run_paragraph = new Run();
    Text text_paragraph = new Text("Hello World!");
    run_paragraph.Append(text_paragraph);
    paragraph.Append(run_paragraph);
    body.Append(paragraph);
    mainPart.Document.Append(body);
    mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

I run it and it seems to work correctly.

If you downloaded the OpenXML SDK 2.0 you should also have Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool (a part of the SDK). It allows you to view existing OpenXML documents, validate them and show c# code that you can write to recreate them programatically.

Comment: U have mentioned dlg.Filename. what is dlg?

Comment: Already corrected this, I changed it to make it work in my test application. Take a look at the code now.

Comment: One more thing I want to ask, Want to open the same file which I created using the code WordprocessingDocument mydoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\List\Data\" + TextBox1.Text, true) and still it is not opening the created file. Do I need to use again using ( ) and then {}. If yes then what should I write in {}?

Comment: How can you tell the file is now opened? I suppose you should use using statement here as well. In the { and } you can write myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body to get the contents of the body.

Comment: Before using, using statement, the file used to create in the folder but when i clicked on that, it used to give error. Now after using, using statement, it is not giving error. Now u want me to write the code like this:  using (WordprocessingDocument mydoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\List\Data\" + TextBox1.Text, true))
        {
           
            mydoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

        } but this is giving error

Comment: What kind of error is it? Name of the exception's type or some description would be helpful ;).

Comment: got the solution, I thought the file will open in a new window but later on came to know that the file will open in background and the text is added to it which v cannot see.